What is the ruling on using "clickbait" titles?
I have recently encountered videos that use similar titles such as "Allah chose you to find this video. Don't scroll away." I worry that this is might be makruh or much worse as the content creators make such heavy claims or declarations in their titles without proper evidence or backing since it implies knowledge in the Divine Will.

This is only what I found with a quick search in the Quran and Hadiths:
"Do not follow what you have no ˹sure˺ knowledge of. Indeed, all will be called to account for ˹their˺ hearing, sight, and intellect." (Quran, 17:36)
"Do not falsely declare with your tongues, “This is lawful, and that is unlawful,” ˹only˺ fabricating lies against Allah. Indeed, those who fabricate lies against Allah will never
succeed." (Quran, 16:116)

Are making such claims in titles permissible? I hope that this is just waswas because I understand that Allah only gives guidance to those whom he wills.

I guess it is not only makruh but straight out haram and a great evil to misuse the name of Allah, but I lack references.
